# C++ Как создать таймер?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как создать таймер в C++? Пробовал SetTimer с USER_TIMER_MINIMUM но он медленный, нужен таймер с интервалом больше 60 раз в секунду

Comment: Почему бы не использовать стандартный `<chrono>` ?

Comment: А как его использовать, не подскажете? Дополнить ответ можно кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/894880/edit).

Comment: @wrbtmrwbt, А где вы увидели таймеры в chrono?

Answer (score 0):

Да, WM_TIMER для серьезных задач подходит слабо. Попробуйте [Timer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa741307(v=vs.94)) - по идее он как раз и предоставляет точные таймеры с высоким разрешением.